# M1Macでrbenv install 2.7.2を実行時、エラーが発生してインストールできません

Tags: ruby, macos, rbenv

#### やりたいこと

Ruby2.7.2をインストールしたい

なかなかうまくいかないので教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします！

#### 環境

Ruby 2.6.5
M1チップ搭載MacOS

#### 前提条件

Homebrewインストール済
rbenvインストール済

#### 発生したエラー

```
Downloading openssl-1.1.1i.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/e8be6a35fe41d10603c3cc635e93289ed00bf34b79671a3a4de64fcee00d5242
Installing openssl-1.1.1i...
Installed openssl-1.1.1i to /Users/yunyun_jp/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2

Downloading ruby-2.7.2.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.7/ruby-2.7.2.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.7.2...
ruby-build: using readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (macOS 11.4 using ruby-build 20210119)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/s2/bcsz8yb94990dsrrg332gxw40000gn/T/ruby-build.20210702152126.84842.ESLM2k
Results logged to /var/folders/s2/bcsz8yb94990dsrrg332gxw40000gn/T/ruby-build.20210702152126.84842.log

Last 10 log lines:
compiling date_parse.c
installing default console libraries
compiling date_strftime.c
compiling date_strptime.c
linking shared-object objspace.bundle
linking shared-object io/nonblock.bundle
linking shared-object io/console.bundle
linking shared-object nkf.bundle
linking shared-object date_core.bundle
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

/var/folders/s2/bcsz8yb94990dsrrg332gxw40000gn/T/ruby-build.20210702152126.84842.log
文字数制限のため一部抜粋

```
linking shared-object gdbm.bundle
readline.c:1904:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'username_completion_function'; did you mean 'rl_username_completion_function'?
                                    rl_username_completion_function);
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                    rl_username_completion_function
readline.c:79:42: note: expanded from macro 'rl_username_completion_function'
# define rl_username_completion_function username_completion_function
                                         ^
/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include/readline/readline.h:485:14: note: 'rl_username_completion_function' declared here
extern char *rl_username_completion_function PARAMS((const char *, int));
             ^
compiling nonblock.c
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [readline.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/readline/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
compiling date_parse.c
installing default console libraries
compiling date_strftime.c
compiling date_strptime.c
linking shared-object objspace.bundle
linking shared-object io/nonblock.bundle
linking shared-object io/console.bundle
linking shared-object nkf.bundle
linking shared-object date_core.bundle
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2

Configuration summary for ruby version 2.7.2

   * Installation prefix: /Users/yunyun_jp/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2
   * exec prefix:         ${prefix}
   * arch:                x86_64-darwin20
   * site arch:           ${arch}
   * RUBY_BASE_NAME:      ruby
   * enable shared:       yes
   * ruby lib prefix:     ${libdir}/${RUBY_BASE_NAME}
   * site libraries path: ${rubylibprefix}/${sitearch}
   * vendor path:         ${rubylibprefix}/vendor_ruby
   * target OS:           darwin20
   * compiler:            clang
   * with pthread:        yes
   * with coroutine:      amd64
   * enable shared libs:  yes
   * dynamic library ext: bundle
   * CFLAGS:              ${optflags} ${debugflags} ${warnflags}
   * LDFLAGS:             -L. -L/Users/yunyun_jp/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib  \
                          -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib
   * DLDFLAGS:            -L/Users/yunyun_jp/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib  \
                          -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup \
                          -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress
   * optflags:            -O3
   * debugflags:          -ggdb3
   * warnflags:           -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations \
                          -Wdivision-by-zero \
                          -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int \
                          -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith \
                          -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings \
                          -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-constant-logical-operand \
                          -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers \
                          -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality \
                          -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare \
                          -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value \
                          -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens
   * strip command:       strip -A -n
   * install doc:         rdoc
   * JIT support:         yes
   * man page type:       doc
   * BASERUBY -v:         ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) \
                          [x86_64-darwin20]

---
    BASERUBY = /Users/yunyun_jp/.rbenv/shims/ruby --disable=gems
    CC = clang
    LD = ld
    LDSHARED = clang -dynamiclib
    CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens -std=gnu99  -fno-common -pipe 
    XCFLAGS = -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT -DCANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin20 -I./include -I. -I./enc/unicode/12.1.0
    CPPFLAGS = -I/Users/yunyun_jp/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   
    DLDFLAGS = -L/Users/yunyun_jp/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib  -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -install_name /Users/yunyun_jp/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/libruby.2.7.dylib -compatibility_version 2.7 -current_version 2.7.2  -fstack-protector-strong -framework Security -framework Foundation  -fstack-protector-strong -framework Security -framework Foundation  
    SOLIBS = -lpthread -ldl -lobjc
    LANG = ja_JP.UTF-8
    LC_ALL = 
    LC_CTYPE = 
    MFLAGS = - --jobserver-fds=6,7 -j
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
compiling ./main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling miniinit.c
compiling dmyext.c
translating probes probes.d
compiling ast.c
compiling bignum.c
compiling class.c
compiling compar.c
. ./vm_opts.h
compiling complex.c
compiling compile.c
compiling cont.c
compiling debug.c
In file included from cont.c:16:
./mjit.h:131:17: warning: cast to smaller integer type 'enum rb_mjit_iseq_func' from 'mjit_func_t' (aka 'unsigned long (*)(struct rb_execution_context_struct *, struct rb_control_frame_struct *)') [-Wpointer-to-enum-cast]
        switch ((enum rb_mjit_iseq_func)func) {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compiling debug_counter.c
compiling dir.c
compiling dln_find.c
compiling encoding.c
compiling enum.c
1 warning generated.
compiling enumerator.c
compiling error.c
compiling eval.c
compiling file.c
In file included from eval.c:20:
./mjit.h:131:17: warning: cast to smaller integer type 'enum rb_mjit_iseq_func' from 'mjit_func_t' (aka 'unsigned long (*)(struct rb_execution_context_struct *, struct rb_control_frame_struct *)') [-Wpointer-to-enum-cast]
        switch ((enum rb_mjit_iseq_func)func) {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compiling gc.c
In file included from gc.c:41:
./mjit.h:131:17: warning: cast to smaller integer type 'enum rb_mjit_iseq_func' from 'mjit_func_t' (aka 'unsigned long (*)(struct rb_execution_context_struct *, struct rb_control_frame_struct *)') [-Wpointer-to-enum-cast]
        switch ((enum rb_mjit_iseq_func)func) {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compiling hash.c
1 warning generated.
compiling inits.c
compiling io.c
compiling iseq.c
compiling load.c
In file included from iseq.c:30:
./mjit.h:131:17: warning: cast to smaller integer type 'enum rb_mjit_iseq_func' from 'mjit_func_t' (aka 'unsigned long (*)(struct rb_execution_context_struct *, struct rb_control_frame_struct *)') [-Wpointer-to-enum-cast]
        switch ((enum rb_mjit_iseq_func)func) {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
iseq.c:3097:27: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'st_data_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        int traced_insn = insn;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~   ^~~~
compiling marshal.c
compiling math.c
making mjit_config.h
compiling mjit_compile.c
In file included from mjit_compile.c:19:
./mjit.h:131:17: warning: cast to smaller integer type 'enum rb_mjit_iseq_func' from 'mjit_func_t' (aka 'unsigned long (*)(struct rb_execution_context_struct *, struct rb_control_frame_struct *)') [-Wpointer-to-enum-cast]
        switch ((enum rb_mjit_iseq_func)func) {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compiling node.c
compiling numeric.c
compiling object.c
2 warnings generated.
compiling pack.c
1 warning generated.
compiling parse.c
compiling proc.c
compiling process.c
compiling random.c
1 warning generated.
compiling range.c
compiling rational.c
compiling re.c
compiling regcomp.c
compiling regenc.c
compiling regerror.c
compiling regexec.c
compiling regparse.c
compiling regsyntax.c
compiling ruby.c
In file included from ruby.c:55:
./mjit.h:131:17: warning: cast to smaller integer type 'enum rb_mjit_iseq_func' from 'mjit_func_t' (aka 'unsigned long (*)(struct rb_execution_context_struct *, struct rb_control_frame_struct *)') [-Wpointer-to-enum-cast]
        switch ((enum rb_mjit_iseq_func)func) {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compiling safe.c
compiling signal.c
compiling sprintf.c
compiling st.c
1 warning generated.
compiling strftime.c
compiling string.c
compiling struct.c
compiling symbol.c
compiling thread.c
In file included from thread.c:77:
./mjit.h:131:17: warning: cast to smaller integer type 'enum rb_mjit_iseq_func' from 'mjit_func_t' (aka 'unsigned long (*)(struct rb_execution_context_struct *, struct rb_control_frame_struct *)') [-Wpointer-to-enum-cast]
        switch ((enum rb_mjit_iseq_func)func) {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compiling time.c
compiling transcode.c
compiling transient_heap.c
compiling util.c
compiling variable.c
compiling vm.c
compiling vm_backtrace.c
compiling vm_dump.c
In file included from vm.c:341:
./mjit.h:131:17: warning: cast to smaller integer type 'enum rb_mjit_iseq_func' from 'mjit_func_t' (aka 'unsigned long (*)(struct rb_execution_context_struct *, struct rb_control_frame_struct *)') [-Wpointer-to-enum-cast]
        switch ((enum rb_mjit_iseq_func)func) {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compiling vm_trace.c
1 warning generated.
compiling ./missing/explicit_bzero.c
compiling ./missing/setproctitle.c
In file included from vm_trace.c:28:
./mjit.h:131:17: warning: cast to smaller integer type 'enum rb_mjit_iseq_func' from 'mjit_func_t' (aka 'unsigned long (*)(struct rb_execution_context_struct *, struct rb_control_frame_struct *)') [-Wpointer-to-enum-cast]
        switch ((enum rb_mjit_iseq_func)func) {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from vm.c:350:
./vm_method.c:291:32: warning: cast to smaller integer type 'enum method_optimized_type' from 'void *' [-Wvoid-pointer-to-enum-cast]
            def->body.optimize_type = (enum method_optimized_type)opts;
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compiling addr2line.c
compiling dmyenc.c
compiling dln.c
compiling localeinit.c
compiling array.c
compiling mjit.c
1 warning generated.
In file included from mjit.c:18:
In file included from ./mjit_worker.c:76:
./mjit.h:131:17: warning: cast to smaller integer type 'enum rb_mjit_iseq_func' from 'mjit_func_t' (aka 'unsigned long (*)(struct rb_execution_context_struct *, struct rb_control_frame_struct *)') [-Wpointer-to-enum-cast]
        switch ((enum rb_mjit_iseq_func)func) {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
assembling coroutine/amd64/Context.S
compiling enc/ascii.c
config.status: creating ruby-runner.h
compiling enc/us_ascii.c
compiling enc/unicode.c
1 warning generated.
compiling enc/utf_8.c
compiling enc/trans/newline.c
./revision.h unchanged
compiling version.c
In file included from version.c:15:
./mjit.h:131:17: warning: cast to smaller integer type 'enum rb_mjit_iseq_func' from 'mjit_func_t' (aka 'unsigned long (*)(struct rb_execution_context_struct *, struct rb_control_frame_struct *)') [-Wpointer-to-enum-cast]
        switch ((enum rb_mjit_iseq_func)func) {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
2 warnings generated.
building rb_mjit_header.h
linking miniruby
rb_mjit_header.h updated
generating encdb.h
building .ext/include/x86_64-darwin20/rb_mjit_min_header-2.7.2.h
./miniruby -I./lib -I. -I.ext/common  ./tool/transform_mjit_header.rb "clang  -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens -std=gnu99  -fno-common -pipe " rb_mjit_header.h .ext/include/x86_64-darwin20/rb_mjit_min_header-2.7.2.h
compiling builtin.c
encdb.h updated
./tool/ifchange "--timestamp=.rbconfig.time" rbconfig.rb rbconfig.tmp
rbconfig.rb updated
generating enc.mk
creating verconf.h
making srcs under enc
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `srcs'.
generating transdb.h
verconf.h updated
compiling loadpath.c
linking static-library libruby.2.7-static.a

Transforming external functions to static:
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_lvar_exposed' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'Init_vm_stack_canary' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_opt_struct_aset' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_opt_struct_aref' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_eql_opt' static inline
transform_mjit_header: changing definition of 'rb_equal_opt' to declaration
transform_mjit_header: changing definition of 'rb_vm_search_method_slowpath' to declaration
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_rewrite_cref' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_block_ep_update' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_cref_new_toplevel' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_frame_block_handler' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_cframe_empty_keyword_p' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_cframe_keyword_p' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_ep_local_ep' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'rb_vm_lvar_exposed' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'rb_vm_rewrite_cref' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'rb_vm_frame_block_handler' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'rb_vm_block_ep_update' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'rb_vm_ep_local_ep' static inline
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sigbits
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'Init_vm_stack_canary' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'rb_eql_opt' static inline
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sincospi
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sincospif
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sincos
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sincosf
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnormall
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnormald
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnormalf
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_signbitl
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_signbitd
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_signbitf
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnanl
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnand
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnanf
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isinfl
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isinfd
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isinff
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isfinitel
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isfinited
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isfinitef
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __darwin_fd_clr
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __darwin_fd_set
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __darwin_fd_isset
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __darwin_check_fd_set
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sputc
linking shared-library libruby.2.7.dylib
transdb.h updated
ln -sf ../../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin20/rb_mjit_min_header-2.7.2.h include/ruby-2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/rb_mjit_min_header-2.7.2.h
generating makefiles ext/configure-ext.mk
making enc
making trans
compiling ./enc/trans/transdb.c
compiling ./enc/encdb.c
compiling ./enc/big5.c
compiling ./enc/cesu_8.c
compiling ./enc/trans/big5.c
ext/configure-ext.mk updated
compiling ./enc/trans/cesu_8.c
compiling ./enc/cp949.c
compiling ./enc/emacs_mule.c
configuring strscan
compiling ./enc/trans/chinese.c
compiling ./enc/euc_jp.c
compiling ./enc/trans/ebcdic.c
compiling ./enc/euc_kr.c
configuring monitor
compiling ./enc/euc_tw.c
compiling ./enc/trans/emoji.c
compiling ./enc/gb2312.c
configuring syslog
compiling ./enc/trans/emoji_iso2022_kddi.c
configuring gdbm
compiling ./enc/gb18030.c
compiling ./enc/gbk.c
configuring pty
compiling ./enc/iso_8859_1.c
compiling ./enc/iso_8859_2.c
configuring objspace
compiling ./enc/trans/emoji_sjis_docomo.c
compiling ./enc/iso_8859_3.c
compiling ./enc/trans/emoji_sjis_kddi.c
compiling ./enc/iso_8859_4.c
compiling ./enc/iso_8859_5.c
configuring nkf
compiling ./enc/trans/emoji_sjis_softbank.c
compiling ./enc/iso_8859_6.c
configuring digest
configuring digest/bubblebabble
configuring digest/md5
compiling ./enc/iso_8859_7.c
compiling ./enc/trans/escape.c
configuring date
compiling ./enc/iso_8859_8.c
compiling ./enc/trans/gb18030.c
configuring readline
compiling ./enc/iso_8859_9.c
compiling ./enc/iso_8859_10.c
compiling ./enc/trans/gbk.c
compiling ./enc/iso_8859_11.c
compiling ./enc/iso_8859_13.c
compiling ./enc/trans/iso2022.c
compiling ./enc/trans/japanese.c
compiling ./enc/iso_8859_14.c
compiling ./enc/iso_8859_15.c
configuring io/console
compiling ./enc/iso_8859_16.c
compiling ./enc/trans/japanese_euc.c
configuring etc
compiling ./enc/koi8_r.c
compiling ./enc/trans/japanese_sjis.c
compiling ./enc/koi8_u.c
compiling ./enc/shift_jis.c
compiling ./enc/utf_16be.c
compiling ./enc/utf_16le.c
configuring io/nonblock
compiling ./enc/utf_32be.c
configuring bigdecimal
compiling ./enc/trans/korean.c
compiling ./enc/utf_32le.c
configuring io/wait
configuring digest/rmd160
compiling ./enc/windows_31j.c
compiling ./enc/windows_1250.c
compiling ./enc/trans/single_byte.c
compiling ./enc/windows_1251.c
compiling ./enc/windows_1252.c
compiling ./enc/windows_1253.c
compiling ./enc/trans/utf8_mac.c
compiling ./enc/windows_1254.c
configuring -test-/arith_seq/extract
configuring -test-/array/resize
configuring -test-/bignum
configuring -test-/bug-14834
configuring -test-/bug-3571
configuring -test-/bug-5832
configuring -test-/bug_reporter
configuring -test-/class
configuring -test-/cxxanyargs
compiling ./enc/windows_1257.c
linking encoding encdb.bundle
linking encoding big5.bundle
configuring -test-/debug
configuring -test-/dln/empty
configuring -test-/enumerator_kw
configuring -test-/exception
configuring -test-/fatal
configuring -test-/file
linking encoding cesu_8.bundle
configuring fiddle
linking encoding cp949.bundle
linking encoding emacs_mule.bundle
configuring digest/sha1
linking encoding euc_jp.bundle
linking encoding euc_kr.bundle
linking encoding euc_tw.bundle
linking encoding gb2312.bundle
compiling ./enc/trans/utf_16_32.c
linking encoding gb18030.bundle
linking encoding gbk.bundle
linking transcoder transdb.bundle
linking encoding iso_8859_1.bundle
linking transcoder big5.bundle
libffi_version: 3.3.0
linking encoding iso_8859_2.bundle
linking transcoder cesu_8.bundle
linking encoding iso_8859_3.bundle
linking transcoder chinese.bundle
linking encoding iso_8859_4.bundle
linking transcoder ebcdic.bundle
linking encoding iso_8859_5.bundle
configuring rubyvm
linking transcoder emoji.bundle
linking encoding iso_8859_6.bundle
configuring zlib
linking transcoder emoji_iso2022_kddi.bundle
linking encoding iso_8859_7.bundle
linking transcoder emoji_sjis_docomo.bundle
linking encoding iso_8859_8.bundle
configuring -test-/float
configuring -test-/funcall
configuring -test-/gvl/call_without_gvl
configuring -test-/hash
configuring -test-/integer
configuring -test-/iseq_load
configuring -test-/iter
configuring -test-/load/dot.dot
configuring -test-/load/protect
linking transcoder emoji_sjis_kddi.bundle
configuring -test-/marshal/compat
configuring -test-/marshal/internal_ivar
configuring -test-/marshal/usr
configuring -test-/memory_status
configuring -test-/method
configuring -test-/notimplement
configuring -test-/num2int
configuring -test-/path_to_class
configuring -test-/popen_deadlock
configuring -test-/postponed_job
configuring -test-/printf
configuring -test-/proc
configuring -test-/rational
configuring -test-/rb_call_super_kw
linking encoding iso_8859_9.bundle
configuring -test-/recursion
configuring -test-/regexp
configuring -test-/scan_args
configuring -test-/st/foreach
configuring -test-/st/numhash
configuring -test-/st/update
configuring -test-/string
configuring -test-/struct
configuring -test-/symbol
linking transcoder emoji_sjis_softbank.bundle
linking encoding iso_8859_10.bundle
linking transcoder escape.bundle
configuring digest/sha2
linking encoding iso_8859_11.bundle
linking transcoder gb18030.bundle
linking encoding iso_8859_13.bundle
linking transcoder gbk.bundle
configuring -test-/thread_fd_close
configuring -test-/time
configuring -test-/tracepoint
linking encoding iso_8859_14.bundle
configuring -test-/typeddata
configuring -test-/vm
configuring -test-/wait_for_single_fd
linking transcoder iso2022.bundle
linking encoding iso_8859_15.bundle
linking transcoder japanese.bundle
linking encoding iso_8859_16.bundle
linking transcoder japanese_euc.bundle
linking encoding koi8_r.bundle
linking transcoder japanese_sjis.bundle
linking encoding koi8_u.bundle
linking transcoder korean.bundle
linking encoding shift_jis.bundle
linking transcoder single_byte.bundle
linking encoding utf_16be.bundle
configuring psych
linking encoding utf_16le.bundle
linking transcoder utf8_mac.bundle
linking encoding utf_32be.bundle
configuring cgi/escape
linking transcoder utf_16_32.bundle
configuring json
configuring json/generator
configuring json/parser
linking encoding utf_32le.bundle
linking encoding windows_31j.bundle
configuring stringio
linking encoding windows_1250.bundle
linking encoding windows_1251.bundle
linking encoding windows_1252.bundle
linking encoding windows_1253.bundle
configuring racc/cparse
linking encoding windows_1254.bundle
linking encoding windows_1257.bundle
configuring fiber
making encs
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `encs'.
configuring sdbm
configuring continuation
configuring rbconfig/sizeof
configuring dbm
configuring fcntl
configuring ripper
configuring openssl
configuring pathname
configuring coverage
configuring socket
header: ndbm.h
library: libc
generating makefile exts.mk
exts.mk updated
compiling monitor.c
compiling strscan.c
compiling syslog.c
compiling gdbm.c
compiling pty.c
compiling nkf.c
compiling digest.c
compiling object_tracing.c
installing default monitor libraries
compiling objspace.c
linking shared-object monitor.bundle
installing default pty libraries
linking shared-object syslog.bundle
linking shared-object pty.bundle
installing default digest libraries
linking shared-object digest.bundle
installing digest libraries
compiling objspace_dump.c
installing default syslog libraries
linking shared-object strscan.bundle
compiling readline.c
compiling date_core.c
compiling console.c
linking shared-object gdbm.bundle
readline.c:1904:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'username_completion_function'; did you mean 'rl_username_completion_function'?
                                    rl_username_completion_function);
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                    rl_username_completion_function
readline.c:79:42: note: expanded from macro 'rl_username_completion_function'
# define rl_username_completion_function username_completion_function
                                         ^
/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include/readline/readline.h:485:14: note: 'rl_username_completion_function' declared here
extern char *rl_username_completion_function PARAMS((const char *, int));
             ^
compiling nonblock.c
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [readline.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/readline/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
compiling date_parse.c
installing default console libraries
compiling date_strftime.c
compiling date_strptime.c
linking shared-object objspace.bundle
linking shared-object io/nonblock.bundle
linking shared-object io/console.bundle
linking shared-object nkf.bundle
linking shared-object date_core.bundle
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

Comment: Rosetta 2 まわりの設定はどのようになさっていますでしょうか。またエラーログに書かれているように、`/var/folders/s2/bcsz8yb94990dsrrg332gxw40000gn/T/ruby-build.20210702152126.84842.log` にログが格納されているようなので中身を確認して質問文に追記いただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 初学者のためよくわからないのですが、ターミナルはRosettaを使用して開くにしています。その他は設定したことはありません。了解です。ログ追記します。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

エラーメッセージから察するに、この issue で track されている問題です https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1691。この回答の投稿時点でまだ open です。

手元に M1 Mac が無く詳しくは調べられていませんが、Rosetta 2 絡みでライブラリか何かの取り扱いに不整合が起こっているように見えます。

[上の issue にあるコメント](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1691#issuecomment-750688557)のように Rosetta 2 を使わずに native の ARM を使うようにするか、他のコメントで触れられている別の workaround を入れると動きそうです。個人的には速度の問題があるので前者がオススメです。

Answer (score 2):

以下のコマンドで自己解決しました。

```
arch -arm64 rbenv install 2.7.2
```

成功時のログ

```
Downloading openssl-1.1.1i.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/e8be6a35fe41d10603c3cc635e93289ed00bf34b79671a3a4de64fcee00d5242
Installing openssl-1.1.1i...
Installed openssl-1.1.1i to /Users/yunyun_jp/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2

Downloading ruby-2.7.2.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.7/ruby-2.7.2.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.7.2...
ruby-build: using readline from homebrew
Installed ruby-2.7.2 to /Users/yunyun_jp/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2
```