# M2 Macでrbenv install 3.1.3を実行時、エラーが発生してインストールできない

Tags: ruby, macos, cocoapods, rbenv

## やりたいこと

Ruby3.1.3をインストールしたい

## 環境

M2 MacBook Air macOS Monterey バージョン 12.5.1
Homebrew 3.6.12
rbenv 1.2.0
ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]

### 経緯

もともとはCocoapodsをインストールしたかったのですが、以下のようなエラーが出ました。

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory.
```

そこで、[こちらの記事](https://qiita.com/ryamate/items/e51c77fbabc2aec185fc)を参考に、一般ユーザの領域にrubyの環境を作ろうとしていました。

```
rbenv install 3.1.3
```

を実行したところ、以下のようなエラーが発生しました。

```
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/3.1/ruby-3.1.3.tar.gz
Installing ruby-3.1.3...
ruby-build: using readline from homebrew
ruby-build: using gmp from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (macOS 12.5.1 using ruby-build 20221124)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/w5/592h_r3d57547m_h6k0tywk80000gn/T/ruby-build.20221126180230.2526.AiU8cm
Results logged to /var/folders/w5/592h_r3d57547m_h6k0tywk80000gn/T/ruby-build.20221126180230.2526.log

Last 10 log lines:
compiling ossl_x509ext.c
compiling ossl_x509name.c
linking shared-object psych.bundle
compiling ossl_x509req.c
3 warnings generated.
compiling ossl_x509revoked.c
compiling ossl_x509store.c
linking shared-object openssl.bundle
linking shared-object ripper.bundle
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

/var/folders/w5/592h_r3d57547m_h6k0tywk80000gn/T/ruby-build.20221126180230.2526.logの内容です。文字数制限のため一部です

```
compiling psych.c
compiling ripper.c
readline.c:1903:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'username_completion_function'; did you mean 'rl_username_completion_function'?
                                    rl_username_completion_function);
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                    rl_username_completion_function
readline.c:79:42: note: expanded from macro 'rl_username_completion_function'
# define rl_username_completion_function username_completion_function
                                         ^
/usr/local/opt/readline/include/readline/readline.h:494:14: note: 'rl_username_completion_function' declared here
extern char *rl_username_completion_function (const char *, int);
             ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [readline.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/readline/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
checking ../.././parse.y and ../.././ext/ripper/eventids2.c
installing default libraries

compiling ossl_pkey_dh.c
compiling ossl_pkey_dsa.c
ossl_pkey_dh.c:87:14: warning: 'DH_new' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        dh = DH_new();
             ^
/Users/komatsu/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/openssl/include/openssl/macros.h:62:52: note: expanded from macro 'OSSL_DEPRECATED'
#     define OSSL_DEPRECATED(since) __attribute__((deprecated))
                                                   ^
44 warnings generated.
compiling ossl_x509.c
compiling ossl_x509attr.c
40 warnings generated.
compiling ossl_x509cert.c
linking shared-object date_core.bundle
compiling ossl_x509crl.c
compiling ossl_x509ext.c
compiling ossl_x509name.c
linking shared-object psych.bundle
compiling ossl_x509req.c
3 warnings generated.
compiling ossl_x509revoked.c
compiling ossl_x509store.c
linking shared-object openssl.bundle
linking shared-object ripper.bundle
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

## やったこと

Xcode再インストール

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
```

[こちらの記事](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/77921/m1mac%E3%81%A7rbenv-install-2-7-2%E3%82%92%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C%E6%99%82-%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E7%99%BA%E7%94%9F%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93)を参考に下記コードを実行

```
arch -arm64 rbenv install 3.1.3
```

[こちらの記事](https://qiita.com/mikan3rd/items/d1dfd7cb62cc23393dd9)を参考にCommandLineToolsの再インストール.zshに環境変数の追加、openssl@1.1の指定なども行いました。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました

## やったこと

homebrewの再インストール
OpenSSLがインストールされていないことを確認

```
brew list | grep openssl
```

ruby 3.1.xはOpenSSL3を要求するらしい

```
brew install openssl@3 readline libyaml gmp
export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@3)"
```

普通にインストールしたら通った

```
rbenv install 3.1.3
rbenv global 3.1.3
rbenv versions
```

.zshrcを編集

```
open ~/.zshrc
```

```
# rbenv にパスを通す
[[ -d ~/.rbenv  ]] && \
  export PATH=${HOME}/.rbenv/bin:${PATH} && \
  eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

sourceコマンドを実行

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

## 参考記事

[ruby-build](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/wiki#build-failure-of-fiddle-with-ruby-220)
[Missing OpenSSL](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/discussions/1961#discussioncomment-4031745)
[エラーが出て、 CocoaPods をインストールできない。](https://qiita.com/ryamate/items/e51c77fbabc2aec185fc)